# .htaccess losing URL parameters/$_GET and $_POST after redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, post-redirect-get

I have a php file like: http://www.domain.com/?mod=test&act=view

And I want to create a redirection from that address to something like: http://www.domain.com/view-test

so that everytime a user accesses the first uri it gets redirected to http://www.domain.com/view-test viewing the content of the first uri.

I have the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mod=test&act=view
RewriteRule ^$ view-test? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^view-test.html amas/index.php?mod=test&act=view [L]
```

This works fine for pages without parameters or forms submissions but If I have any of those nothing works.

Meaning that if I have a form that is submitting to the same file it won't work. If i have something like http://domain.com/?mod=test&act=view&order_by=id i'm left with the redirected to uri and the order_by parameter is ignored!

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying? I don't really know much about this and to be honest I'm lost between all the info I find... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Query String Append:

```
RewriteRule ^view-test.html amas/index.php?mod=test&act=view [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for the reply!! There is a problem with that rule... The final url is: http://www.domain.com/view-test?mod=test&act=view&order_by=id instead of http://www.domain.com/view-test&order_by=id anyway to solve this? Thanks